# How to do Heroku-like Delayed Jobs in C#.NET?

Tags: .net, windows, queue, msmq, delayed-job

Would like to implement something similar to this for our C#.NET Web App.
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queueing

What pre-existing solutions are already out there that will work with .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I am looking for something similar. The library closest to DelayedJob seems to be Quartz.net http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html

Obviously we wont get certain features from DJ, like prepend a function name with delayed to delay the execution of the function, in the .Net world...

Comment: We found Quartz too. Seems interesting, but like you said not quite a complete solution.

Please post back anything else you find.

Will leave the question open a bit longer, but if no other replies come in I'll award the solution to you.